# Prepared Statement query syntax error

Tags: mysql

Please can anyone tell me why this `stored procedure` is not working , what am I doing wrong.It keeps giving syntax error.

`puserid and plimit` are the parameters passed in the procedure.

```
DECLARE uid BIGINT;
DECLARE rangee TINYINT;
SET @uid    = puserid;
SET @rangee = plimit * 15;


PREPARE STMT FROM 
'IF((SELECT count(type) from notificationrecievers nr where 
nr.status=0 and nr.recieverid=?) = 0) THEN
select nr.type,n.senderid,n.postid,u.name,nr.status
 from 
 user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr where 
 nr.recieverid=? and u.userid=n.senderid   and
 nr.notificationid=n.notid order by n.notid desc
limit 15 OFFSET ?;
ELSE
select nr.type,n.senderid,n.postid,u.name,nr.status
 from 
 user u,notifications n,notificationrecievers nr where 
 nr.recieverid=? and u.userid=n.senderid   and nr.status=0 and
 nr.notificationid=n.notid order by n.notid desc;
END IF;';

EXECUTE STMT USING @uid,@uid,@rangee,@uid;
```

Here's the error that i get.

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF((SELECT count(type) from notificationrecievers nr where nr.status=0 and nr.r' at line 1
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? while creating PROCEDURE or while EXECUTING it? I could create this procedure just fine.

Comment: i get this error while executing the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only DML in prepared statements.
You can do something like this

```
IF condition THEN
  set @q = 'your query text'
ELSE
  set @q = 'another query'
END IF;

PREPARE stmt FROM @q
EXECUTE stmt using ...
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

You can execute some queries before to evaluate your conditions.
Hope it helps